# Directory outside of project base directory. Maven-war-plugin - <webResources>

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, warnings, maven-plugin

I have Maven Problems warning in Eclipse, because of my pom.xml war-plugin configuration.

The project has multi modules. The hierarchy is here:
[Project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJJPX.jpg)

I need to pack content of specific directory (webapp in module2) to module. The main part of top pom.xml configuration is here:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>../module2/src/main/webapp</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <packagingExcludes>**/*.db,**/*.scss,**/*.example,**/abrepository/**,,**/abconnection.xml</packagingExcludes>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

The main part of module configuration is here:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <warName>modul</warName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

With this war-plugin config I have this warning which I want to exlude:

```
***module\..\module2\src\main\webapp" directory outside of project base directory. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.2.0:war:default-war:package)    pom.xml /module line 1  Maven Build Participant Problem
```

Can I get rid of it, or can I add the content of the folder (webapp) to .war package in different way?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Simply move the directory into the module where you have the war plugin...?

Comment: But I need the same directory in multiple modules.

Comment: That sounds like you are doing it wrong. Make a separate module as jar and add a dependency to it...Or better explain what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: In configuration you can see the excluded files. I need to add some .css and so on to multiple modules. So this is the bad way to achieve it? Should I add these files into .jar and then in every module add it with dependency config? Thanks.

Comment: If those are css etc. I would recommend to create a separate war module which contains only those modules and use maven-war-plugin overlay mechanism...

Comment: I do not understand much. I have multiple modules, and in one module I have some web content, which I want to add to all other modules .war files. I dont want to copy the same content to all modules again. How can I add the webcontent (webapp folder) from one module to others (6 modules) when the source module is also the dependency of the others (all six modules have dependency to this module in pom.xml).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what @altair is doing, but it's common to manage web front-end files like an Angular app as a separate project, and copy the built result into a back-end spring-boot app at build time. It would be great to have first-class support for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the overwriting version warning, where on can add a comment "$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$" after the version, there does not seem to exist an elegant solution to this problem so far.

The only thing you can do (and I did in my case) is to disable "Maven Build Participant Problems" alltogether:

- Problems View -> Arrow down button in the tor-right corner
- "Configure Contents"
- In your active config, deactivate within "Maven Problems" the check box "Maven Build Participant Problems"

[image]